# 5v clock feeding 3.3v microcontroller - resistor+zener acceptable?

Tags: clock, level-shifting

So I've used a resistor and diode to level-shift from 5v to 3.3v, but that's been for general logic - the fastest thing I've done with that is 9600 bps serial.

I now have a need to feed a 3.3v powered microcontroller (an ATXMega32E5) from a 10 MHz clock signal, which I only presently have available as a 5v square wave (an output from an NB3N551 powered at 5v).

I propose to use a 10 kΩ series resistor followed by a 3.3v zener diode. Circuitlab simulation seems to show this would work, but I am not sure I trust it to be a complete enough simulation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEXVR9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is that simple zener clipper likely to work acceptably, or is something more sophisticated called for?

Comment: No need for more sophistication. However, Zeners usually have substantial capacitance, so 10k-RC might filter quite a lot from 10 MHz clock. Use a simple resistor divider, 500/1000 Ohms or something. Or maybe nothing at all, the output voltage swing of oscillator is likely much less than 5 V.

Comment: Do you know the slew rate needed for 10MHz at say 10% ramp?  Normally drivers are 25~75 Ohms not 10k. This demands knowing all component and stray capacitance. So not too good.

Comment: Why are you running NB3N551 on 5V when it runs on 3.3V which is what you need? Keep connections short or controlled impedance.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 The NB3N551 feeds *other* things that must get 5v output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If capacitance (track + diode+ load) is 30pF at 0V with 10k the rise time ~ 300ns in a 50 ns half cycle.  Even a Rohm low capacitance zener=3pF + 3pF optimal load is 60 ns rise time.   No good.  Use an active level converter.

Comment: While it's true that the proposed 10K resistor will not work, it's not at all valid to leap from that to assuming that active conversion is needed.

Comment: maybe, but under 100 Ohms is needed with stray, trace and load capacitance with say 10pF and 2% slope, and power sequencing to ensure Vdd before input. An active translator gaurantees this.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I use a 74AHC1G04DBV elsewhere to perform a sine-to-square conversion (as a self-biased inverter). What do you think of using one here as a level shifter? The fact that the phase changes doesn't matter.

Comment: I gather its close the clock and runs on 3.3V and the connection is farther away? and power sequence is guaranteed to not cause latchup on the target?  You cant drive CMOS before power is applied.

Comment: All of this is inside of a ~1 sq in area. The 3.3v comes from an LDO powered from the 5v bus. The LDO spec is 50µs startup, and the clock startup is delayed way beyond that relative to power-up (which is ok because the controller ignores the external clock until way, way later).

Comment: Sounds ok......

Comment: compute voltage drops from IC ,  if low pF load try a passive level shifter IC=~50 ohm(Vol/Iol)+ 170 series + 330 ohm shunt =132 ohm source 3.3V